# Android virtual keyboard (Rugby Pro) types j when I press g (and other keyboard mismaps)

Tags: keyboard

This description is bad but I have been struggling with finding the right words. I searched SE for "android virtual keyboard loses touch mapping" and nothing that looked right came back.

1. Have a Galaxy Rugby Pro with Android 4.2 stock. Using standard Samsung keyboard app with occasional Google Voice.
2. Every three months or so, my Android phone virtual keyboard seems to lose its mappings.
3. Meaning, when I type a g, the keyboard actually registers a j. Same with other keys, usually in the central row but also has included backspace, space bar.
4. This only happens in the keyboard that comes up in portrait mode for messaging and Facebook, etc. Does not happen in landscape (which I don't use much, unless the problems with portrait are significantly hampering me).
5. I've tried app manager/samsung keyboard/reset keyboard. No luck.
6. The only thing that works for me is [to reset the phone completely](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/681807-issue-wrong-letter-selected-samsung-keyboard.html) with a factory reset.
7. That always fixes it, but reinstalling apps, redoing logins, etc is a PITA. I don't think backups are the answer because reinstalling would just reinstall the bad keyboard mapping.

### So, two questions

A. Is there any way I can prevent the problem from happening without doing a full phone reset?

B. What terms should I use in googling this problem? "Android keyboard mapping" just leads me to links about, well, keyboard mapper apps. "android keyboard wrong letters" brings me to the link about the factory reset and other not-useful items about installing non-english keyboard layouts, which is not my issue.

Comment: Use another keyboard, Google has a good one on the play store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *For a fix*

1. Open settings>apps
2. Go the all tab, swipe left 2x's
3. Scroll down to Samsung Keyboard and tap it
4. Tap on force close, then ok
5. Tap on clear cache
6. Tap on clear data, then ok

Problem should be fixed!!!

## *Google search keywords*

*galaxy rugby keyboard typing wrong letters*

Comment: This exactly fixed my problem. Thanks so much. Now I won't need to Google any longer because this URL is the answer.

Comment: @lonstar you are very welcome,  glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

My Android Rii keyboard started to play up and I tried changing the settings and clearing the cache and data but still got the wrong characters. I found the [Multilingual Keymap Redefiner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=innerlife.keyboard.multilanguagekeymapredefiner&hl=en) app and remapped the failing keys. I couldn't download it from the Play Store in the UK so had to search for the apk and download and install manually but works a treat.